# How to start animated rotation of element from the angle that previous animated rotation ended? (WPF, XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, rotation, storyboard

Firstly I searched lot of similar Q&As but I couldnt tune none for my needs. Secondly I am beginner in WPF and XAML (after moved from WinForms). I need to solve much more complicated elements composition but after hard simplification it is like this: I need to be able to rotate a Grid, by 90degree animated steps left or right, by simply clicking on two (Left and Right) buttons, multiple times. So 4 clicks on the same button means complete circle - initial position of the Grid. So it is not about direct element "jump" rotation, but rather about applying two available storyboards(animations), multiple times on same element. My problem is, that the element "returns (or keeps)" to its initial angle before any storyboard is ran again. Visually it is rendered rotated, but I think somewhere underground it is not :)
These questions are on my mind:
-How to "keep" new angle of the Grid after the animated_rotation ends (before new eventual rotation comes)?
-Or How and Where(codebehind/xaml) to apply increasing/dereasing of 90° angle?

Finally I end up with this state. It works nicely one click left (-90), one click right (+90), and then nothing.

```
Window x:Name="RotoTest" 
        x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="rototest" Height="179.612" Width="198" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>


    <StackPanel Margin="0,-1,0,0" Height="162" VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="RotateLEFT">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="GridRoto" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Completed="RotationRIGHT_completed" >
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value ="-90">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.3"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Key="RotateRIGHT">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="GridRoto" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Completed="RotationRIGHT_completed" >
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value ="90">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Amplitude="0.3"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Viewbox x:Name="ViewboxRoto" Height="100">
            <Grid x:Name="GridRoto" Height="100" Width="100" Background="#FFC72323" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="22,42,26,36"/>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>

        <Button Content="RotoLEFT" x:Name="Btn_RotoLEFT">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateLEFT}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>

        <Button Content="RotoRIGHT" x:Name="Btn_RotoRIGHT">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateRIGHT}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
      
    </StackPanel>

</Window>

/////////Codebehind:

Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Btn_RotoLEFT_clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Btn_RotoLEFT.Click
        'another stuff
    End Sub
    Private Sub Btn_RotoRIGHT_clicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Btn_RotoRIGHT.Click
        'another stuff
    End Sub
    Public Sub RotationLEFT_completed()
        'another stuff
        MessageBox.Show("90 Rotation LEFT completed")
    End Sub
    Public Sub RotationRIGHT_completed()
        'another stuff
        MessageBox.Show("90 Rotation RIGHT completed")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Instead of DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames use a DoubleAnimation with `By="90"`.

Comment: I cant believe how easy can profi answer be! (I spent days n days...) It works very fine. Thank you very much!!!